# pandas apply list value from one column to another

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
     description.    lineItem
0.                   [{'description': 'invoice4}]
1                    [{'description': 'invoice3}]
2                    [{'description': 'invoice2}]
3.    "invoice1"
```

I am trying to update column 'description' so that it takes the value from the dict in the lineItem array so that it should look like:

```
     description.    lineItem
0.    'invoice4'    [{'description': 'invoice4}]
1     'invoice3'    [{'description': 'invoice3}]
2     'invoice2'    [{'description': 'invoice2}]
3.    'invoice1'
```

I have tried all sorts of array and dict accessors, but the type of lineItem seems to be `<class 'list'>`.

```
def get_description(lineItem):
    lineItem.str[0]['description]


df.loc[df["description"] == '','description'] = df['lineItems'].apply(getDescription)
```

results in `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

How can I access the lineItem list value?

Comment: `lineItem.[0]['description']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[None,[{'description': 'invoice4'}]],[None,[{'description': 'invoice3'}]],[None,[{'description': 'invoice2'}]],["invoice1",""]
],columns=["description","lineItem"])

df['description'] = df['description'].fillna(df['lineItem'].str[0].str['description'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    description                   lineItem
0    invoice4  [{'description': 'invoice4'}]
1    invoice3  [{'description': 'invoice3'}]
2    invoice2  [{'description': 'invoice2'}]
3    invoice1
```